# How to find the logged in user in Sharepoint2010 SitePage?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to getting any specific information (ID, GUID..) about the logged in user in any sitepage(simple sitepage which has only HTML tags).
But i did not get the below info :

```
<%#
    SPWeb theSite = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context);    
%>
```

I have used the below code snipped

```
    <%#
SPWeb web =  SPContext.Current.Web;
SPUser currentUser =  web.CurrentUser;
%>
```

But get the below error code.

```
 Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Source Error:


Line 1343:                  
Line 1344:              <%#
Line 1345:              SPWeb web =  SPContext.Current.Web;
Line 1346:SPUser currentUser =  web.CurrentUser;
Line 1347:
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the current user:

```
SPWeb web =  SPContext.Current.Web;
SPUser currentUser =  web.CurrentUser;
```

You can then get all the information you need about the user like name, email ,etc:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.aspx

in your case try this:

```
<%= SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Email %>
```

I dont usually use inline code, I preffer to implement this kind of things using custom controls so not sure if this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have also this code can give you the current user

```
this.Page.User.Identity.Name
```

Hop this can help!